# Can a SharePoint 2010 workflow be created with CSOM in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, csom

I would like to be able to create definitions for SharePoint 2010 workflows using XAML from an existing workflow in SharePoint 2013 without deploying a solution.

Sharepoint 2013 includes methods for working with the Workflow Management services via CSOM.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn481315(v=office.15).aspx

These methods appear to be able to create workflow definitions and publish subscriptions, however after reading up on this I believe this only applies to workflows running on the SharePoint 2013 workflow engine.  There is an interop service for interacting with SP2010 workflows, but this appears to be limited to starting and stopping existing workflows.

I have attempted to use CSOM to create SP2010 workflows in SP2013 using existing XAML without success.  Does anyone know whether this should be possible?

Obviously, workflow definitions can be created from a client as this is what SharePoint Designer does, however SPD appears to call a couple of SOAP endpoints and it does not appear to easy to reproduce the process.  Are there any other options?